# How to redirect on button click to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to make a page that has a picture and a button to enter the site. On that button click, you should be redirected inside the home and from where a classic site with a navigation bar.

What I tried is to use history and onClick of a button go home using also React route dom functionalities but I'm unable to navigate from the first page to home.

What I did I set up Router first on my index.js

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
```

Then I added in my App.js

```
 <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Main />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

After that I tried to set the button as follow in my PodCard component

```
const PodCard = (props) => {
  const { title, url, hdurl, explanation, date, copyright } = props.data;

  const routeChange = () => {
    let path = `home`;
    history.push(path);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <img src={url} alt={title} />
      <Button onClick={routeChange}>Enter</Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default PodCard;
```

The PodCard is imported in my main pages where I show the welcome page

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getPod } from "../../API";
import PodCard from "../../Components/Pod";

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      podData: [],
      isFetching: false,
      isLoading: true,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const podData = await getPod();
    this.setState({
      isFetching: true,
      isLoading: false,
      podData: podData,
    });
    console.log("POD State >> ", this.state.podData);
  };

  render() {
    const { podData, isLoading } = this.state;
    return isLoading ? <h1>LOADING...</h1> : <PodCard data={podData} />;
  }
}
```

I want to understand what I do wrong here and how from my Main to navigate clicking on the button to the home page where my site will start actually with a navigation bar.

Comment: have you tried with : let path = "/home"

Comment: Are you receiving a history is undefined when you click? history is an object sent in props. You may also need to use ```export default withRouter(PodCard)``` for history to be accessible inside PodCard.

Comment: personally I would look into ```Link``` from ```react-router-dom```.  You can style it the same way as your button and it does the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: I tried with /home as a path. I change

Comment: I tried also with link but no success too

Answer (score 0):

to make a link to Home, you can write like this:

```
<Route path="/home" />
```

next step in Podcard, you can modified arrow function routeChange like this:

```
const routeChange = () => {
  Router.push({ pathname:'/home' })
 };
```

dont forget to import Router in Podcard
I hope this helps :)

Comment: I made route home in my file as showed in my question but also in this way just nothing happen

Comment: By the way, your solutions give an error
TypeError: react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Router.push is not a function

Comment: what version of your Router  ??

Comment: "react-router": "^5.1.2",
 "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",